# Disable verbose logging of symbol loading in vscode debug console

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

When running my webapp (in vscode), the debug console is filled with lines like these:

> Loaded '/foo/bar/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.4/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

and

> The thread 123 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I thought this has something to do with log filtering in the `appsettings.json` file, but these don't belong to any category I can disable.

This is very annoying - how do I disable it?

Comment: Check [docs here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#logging)

Comment: This should answer as clearly as possible: https://youtu.be/Rc2v2A1TIqI

Answer (score 54, accepted):

These logs are managed by VS Code. You can disable them in the `launch.json` file in the `.vscode` directory. You can add the following node inside any of the elements in the `configurations` node to disable module load messages for that configuration:

```json
"logging": {
    "moduleLoad": false
}
```

There are more options available such as `exceptions` and `programOutput`, check out the Intellisense for all available options.

Comment: I also had "engineLogging": true  under logging. Was trying to figure out why VSCode wasn't working on my computer several months ago and partly forgot about it. I didn't think at first that it was part of the reason for me getting excessive debug console messages.

Comment: Thanks, my log console is now clean enough to eat off of

Answer (score 24):

I came to this answer looking for the same thing as the original question was.  The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684002/1039753) was correct but I did not understand where I needed to put it.  So I decided to add my own answer in hopes of guiding others in the same situation...

All you need to add is the following code to your solution (or project file if you are not working with a solution).

```
"logging": {
    "moduleLoad": false
}
```

Because it was not clear to me where it needs to be added (there was two separate areas un my "configurations" node called "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)" and "name": ".NET Core Attach"), I wanted to post my entire config to make it much more clear.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/example.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "logging": {
            "moduleLoad": false
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes. I wasted time guessing where the lines should go because I only looked at the accepted answer, when I finally looked at this answer it finally worked.

Comment: Thanks.  ;)  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 5):

The answer correctly explains how to disable logging in the general case (by editing `.vscode/launch.json`).

But that doesn't work for a debug session started from codelens:

[image: Start debug session from codelens]

In that case edit `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
"csharp.unitTestDebuggingOptions": {
  "logging": { "moduleLoad": false }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the accepted answer doesn't work when debugging **Blazor** projects.

Use this instead:

```json
"dotNetConfig": {
  "logging": { "moduleLoad": false }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all the answers above were outdated now. They didn't work for me (ver. 1.83.1). What worked for me was adding the following line in the settings.json file (~/.config/Code/User/settings.json).

```
"csharp.debug.logging.moduleLoad": false
```

Comment: I thinkj so too

Answer (score 0):

To add to the list of answers, this worked for disabling integration tests on VS Code (1.86), C#, and xUnit:

```
    "dotnet.unitTestDebuggingOptions": {
        "logging": {
            "moduleLoad": false
        }
    }
```